# How to display product filter in custom plugin development

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to display default Woo-commerce product filter in my custom plugin development. I have used following short-code for display products.

```
echo do_shortcode("[products]");
```

It's working and product also showing but i also want to display default product filter in Woo-commerce , I used following short-code but default product filter is not showing.

```
[woocommerce_product_filter_products]
[woocommerce_product_filter]
```

Is there another way to display default product filter in plugin development or another pages?

Answer (score 0):

Register a Sidebar:

```
if ( function_exists('shortcodeWidget') )
  register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'Shortode widget for filter',
    'id' => 'shortcode-widget',
    'before_widget' => '<div class = "filterWidget">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h3>',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
  )
);
```

After register the shortcode

```
function shortcodeSidebar(){

  ob_start();
  get_sidebar('shortcode-widget');
  $sidebar= ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();

  return $sidebar;
}

add_shortcode('filterWoocommerce', 'shortcodeSidebar');
```

And then add the filter in the custom widget.